# Upgrade KDE Plasma on Kubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde

For some reason, the latest Kubuntu ships with KDE Plasma 5.5.5, which is at least two minor versions behind the [latest stable release of 5.7.4](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.7.4.php).

How can KDE Plasma be upgraded?

<sub>(This question was already asked for [Kubuntu 14.10 without a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546894/how-to-upgrade-kde-plasma-in-kubuntu-14-10).)</sub>

Comment: Looks like you can get to 5.6.5 using the PPA at  https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that 16.04 was released in April, and the latest point release for it wasn't terribly recent. It would be pretty amazing if 16.04 shipped with a build of KDE that came out about a week ago. According to [KDE's packages page](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Packages), 16.04 actually came wih 5.5.3, so 16.04.1 must have upgraded to 5.5.5.

The page also says that Kubuntu can get Plasma 5.6.5 with Backports from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+index). This isn't the latest version, but it appears that is the latest stable build for Ubuntu. I would recommend you install this one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

In case 5.6.5 isn't new enough, the [Staging branch](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/staging-plasma/+index) happens to have 5.7.2 for Xenial and Yakkety. You can try it out, but it isn't stable, so expect issues. I don't really recommend this, but if you want the latest you can easily get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/staging-plasma
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you really, really, really want 5.7.4, you can build KDE completely from source. The code can be found [here](https://www.kde.org/info/plasma-5.7.4.php) and build instructions [here](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source). There are quite a few packages to build, however, so I recommend you settle for 5.6.5 or 5.7.2. Unless you absolutely have to have 5.7.4 on Ubuntu, the effort needed for this is probably not worth the 0.0.2 point upgrade.

As for the reason there is no 5.7.4 on Ubuntu yet: well, take a look at the source; it's a lot. The Kubuntu team has to build all that for Ubuntu after the KDE team releases it, and make sure it's stable. Then they also have to wait for a new Ubuntu release (xx.04 or xx.10, not xx.xx.Y) to actually package it in by default.

Comment: After installing updates, I ended up with Plasma 5.6.5. It's still [broken in may obvious ways, mainly multi-monitor support and window switching](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=135101&p=363323#p363293).

Comment: @DanDascalescu it's KDE. It was never stable in the sense that other DEs are stable :p. The focus of KDE is more on features than stability, at least how I see it.

Comment: Isn't it too dangerous to add the backports repository. I had bad experience and I had to reinstall the OS because of broken packages (on Kubuntu 14.04). Kubuntu 16.04 is stable and adding not stable repositories doesn't sound like good idea.

Comment: @makkasi I warned against issues, but there's no reason to say not to try it. With anything, there's a possibility of breakage. With unstable packages, the risk is just increased.

Answer (score 4):

Stable releases (5.6.5) can be found in the `backports ppa`. To install do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**PLEASE BE EXTRA CAREFUL WITH THE EXPERIMENTAL PPA.**

Experimental releases (5.7.2) can be found in the `staging ppa`. To install do::

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/staging-plasma -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```