# Problems in re-installing KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kde, plasma

I installed KDE Plasma 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and all was working right.

A few days ago I tried to install a newer version of KDE Plasma (I tried the staging ppa mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820613/upgrade-kde-plasma-on-kubuntu-16-04-1) and other trials) and in some way I broke my KDE.

Now I would like to re-install KDE Plasma 5.6, so tried to first remove all traces of KDE and installing it again, basically following the commands used in the past:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

but now I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: dolphin but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kde-cli-tools but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: khelpcenter but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kinfocenter but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: kwin
                   Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: sddm-theme-breeze but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: systemsettings but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: akregator but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: bluedevil but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kaddressbook but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kate but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-config-sddm but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-telepathy but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdeconnect-plasma but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kmail but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: knotes but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kontact but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: korganizer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kscreen but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kwin-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: milou but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-dataengines-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-nm but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-pa but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-runners-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-wallpapers-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: print-manager but it is not going to be installed
```

What can I do?
Thank you very much
Vincenzo